# Why is $f_n(x) = x^n$ not uniformly convergent on $(0, 1)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Definition of uniform convergence:

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(f_n(x), f(x)) < \epsilon$ for all $n > N \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in (0,1)$.

It's easy to see that for all $x$, $f_n(x) \to 0$ on $(0, 1)$ which means that $f_n$ is pointwise convergent, but since $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ for all $x$, I don't see any counter-examples that we can take $x$ to be in order for $f_n$ to converge to any other limit besides $0$. I also don't see how we can use the definition in order to prove that $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: Intuitively, this is because $1^n=1$, so that the closer you get to $1$, the slower is convergence to $0$. Informally, $f_\infty(<1)=0$ and $f_\infty(1)=1$, the limit function is discontinuous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{x\to1} f_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$. This breaks uniform convergence because we can get close enough to $1$ such that $f_N(x) > \frac12$ for any fixed $N$.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint.** You have $$\sup_{x\in(0,1)}f_n(x)=1.$$

Answer (score 11):

**Hint** If $x_n =1-\frac{1}{n}$ then $f_n(x_n) \to \frac{1}{e}$.

Use this to contradict $d(f_n(x_n), f(x_n))<\epsilon$.

Comment: Clever! I like this answer a lot.

Comment: Hi @N.S. it seems like you have shown that $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent on the half-open interval (0,1], and not on $(0,1)$, from showing that $f(x_n) \to \frac {1}{e} \ne 1 = f(\lim x_n)$.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 No, you don't use the limit at $1$. You just write the definition of uniform convergence on $(0,1)$ and use $x_n \in (0,1)$ to get a contradiction....

Answer (score 2):

We can see this directly. If it were uniformly convergent (to $0$), for any $\varepsilon>0$, we could find $N_0$ such that $0<x^n<\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N_0$ and all $x\in(0,1)$. In particular, $x^{N_0}<\varepsilon$, which is the same as $\,0<x<\varepsilon^{\frac1{N_0}}$ for *all* $x\in(0,1)$. That is impossible.

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Answer (score 2):

What exponent is needed for $(.9)^n$ to be less than $.1$? Answer: 
$$n > \ln(.1) / \ln(.9)
$$

What exponent is needed for $(.99)^n$ to be less than $.1$? Answer: 
$$n > \ln(.1) / \ln(.99)
$$

What exponent is needed for $(.999)^n$ to be less than $.1$? Answer: 
$$n > \ln(.1) / \ln(.999)
$$

What is the limit of these exponents $n$ as the number of $9$'s increases to $+\infty$? Answer: 
$$\lim \, n = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \ln(.1) / \ln(x) = +\infty
$$

Therefore, the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = x^n$ does not converge uniformly to zero on the interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Put $$x=\frac{1+\epsilon}{2}$$
This gives $\epsilon < x < 1$.
Then, $\forall n$,
$$\begin{aligned}
x^n = \bigl(\frac{1+\epsilon}2 \bigr)^n &=\frac{1}{2^n}(1+\epsilon)^n \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\epsilon^k > \frac{1}{2^n} \epsilon \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} =\frac{1}{2^n}  2^n \epsilon=\epsilon ~.\end{aligned}$$
Hence, there is no number $N$ such that $x^N < \epsilon$, when $0 < \epsilon < 1$.
So, uniform convergence fails.