# Does $x^n$ converges uniformly on $ [0,1)?$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Doing the limit we can see that in the open interval it converges pointwise to the constant function $f(x) = 0$. In the closed interval it doesn't converge uniformly because in $x=1$ $f(x) =1$ and when $0<x<1$ then $f(x)=0$. It isn't a continuous function although $f_n(x)$ is continuous for all $n$. So it can't be uniform.

However,let $0<ε<1$, we know the function increases as $x$ increases. So,

$|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq ε^{n}$

And ε^(n) goes to 0 as n tends to infinity. Doesn't it mean that the convergence is uniform?

Comment: You might also want to see these pages: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254285/why-is-f-nx-xn-not-uniformly-convergent-on-0-1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773464/is-xn-uniformly-convergent-on-0-1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean that. Yes, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varepsilon^n=0$, but that is not relevant here. Just note that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac12}\right)^n=\frac12.$$But then $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't converge uniformly to the null function. And, since it does converge pointwise to the null function, you can conclude that it doesn't converge uniformly *at all*.

Comment: I don't get why it isn't relevant. Isn't uniform convergence about finding something greater than |fn(x) - f(x) | that doesn't depend on x and which gets closer to 0 as n tends to infinity?

Comment: It's about, given a number $\varepsilon>0$, to prove that $\bigl\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$ when $n$ is large enough and for **every** $x$ in the domain.

Comment: Using your $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \varepsilon^n$ argument, you are effectively showing (via the squeeze theorem) that if $x\le \varepsilon$, then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$. But to show *uniform* convergence, you would essentially have to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N>0$ (which can depend on $\epsilon$ but **not on $x$**) such that for *all* $x\in[0,1)$, whenever $n > N$, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <  \epsilon$. Your $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \varepsilon^n$ argument didn't show this.

Comment: ε^(n) is greater than any x in the domain [0,ε) because it's an increasing function.

Comment: Why do you write $\varepsilon^{(n)}$ instead of $\varepsilon^n$?

Comment: Even though $\varepsilon > x$ for all $x\in [0,\varepsilon)$, this will not imply uniform convergence on $[0,1)$. You might want to see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773464/is-xn-uniformly-convergent-on-0-1.

Answer (score 2):

No, $x^n$ does not converge to zero uniformly on $[0,1)$, because

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{0\leq x<1}|x^n|=1\neq 0$$

Comment: Where does that expression comes from?

Comment: It comes from the definition of uniform convergence. Have you seen it in your studies? A sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on a set $A$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$. The proof is easy.

Comment: I was trying to apply the definition to solve the original problem

Comment: Go right ahead and apply the definition. Take $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Now I give you some positive integer $N$. Now you find $n>N$ sufficiently large and $x$ sufficiently close to $1$ such that $x^n>\frac{1}{2}=\varepsilon$. 
1. Can you do that?
2. Do you understand why it proves that there is no uniform convergence? 3. Do you see that this process is equivalent to the one line I wrote in my answer?

Comment: @Marco Villalobos, "the definition" is ambiguous thing unless you write it down. To me, uniform convergence in some function space is convergence in [sup norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm), precisely what uniquesolution used in their answer.

Comment: @uniquesolution all right, I see your point, but what if we only study the interval [0,ε]. Applying the same reasoning, x^(n) can't be greater than ε. Moreover, i get points 1 and 2, but i don't see why 3 is equivalent

Comment: We do have uniform convergence on $[0,\varepsilon]$ for any constant $\varepsilon$ with $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. But this does not imply uniform convergence on $[0,1)$.

Comment: @minusOne-Twelfth That's where i was trying to get! But ε can be arbitrarily close to 1, so why not in the open interval?

Comment: See this question maybe, it's asking a similar thing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773464/is-xn-uniformly-convergent-on-0-1.

Comment: The problem is, even though $\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$, you have to **fix** the value of $\varepsilon$. Once you fix it, no matter how close to $1$ it is, given any $N > 0$, there will exist an $n \ge N$ and an $x\in [0,1)$ such that $x^n \ge 1/2$ (say); by definition, this implies that we don't have uniform convergence. Such $x$ may well have to be *extremely* close to $1$, even greater than $\varepsilon$! But the key is that $\varepsilon$ is fixed, so no matter how close to $1$ it is, we will be able to get $x$ even closer to $1$ and have $x^n \ge 1/2$.

Comment: By the way, you may also like to see the answer here to possibly gain some intuition for uniform convergence in general: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679951/the-difference-between-pointwise-convergence-and-uniform-convergence-of-function.